# Compound Interest Calculator in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, calculator

The code below is a quick, working example of a compound interest table I wrote. My concern is mainly about separating the application data/logic from the UI code. I didn't use any frameworks on purpose, just because this is an exercise.

**Here's the code**

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  function clearContents(tag) {
    while (tag.firstChild) {
      tag.removeChild(tag.firstChild);
    }
  }


  function addValueToRow(rowTag, value) {
    var newValue = document.createElement("td");
    newValue.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
    rowTag.appendChild(newValue);
  }


  function formatMoney(value) {
    return value.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }


  function main() {
    var inputBoxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var table = document.getElementById("results");
    var monthlyContributionInput = document.getElementById("monthly-contribution");
    var numberOfYearsInput = document.getElementById("year-count");
    var annualInterestRateInput = document.getElementById("annual-interest-rate");
    var updateTable = function(event) {
      var rowcount = Number(numberOfYearsInput.value);
      var monthlyContribution = Number(monthlyContributionInput.value);
      var annualInterestRate = Number(annualInterestRateInput.value) / 100.0;
      var interestFactor = 1 + annualInterestRate / 12.0;
      var balance = 0;
      var totalDeposit = 0;
      var monthCount = 0;
      var yearInterest = 0;
      var perviousYearInterest = 0;
      clearContents(table);
      for (var row = 1; row <= rowcount; row += 1) {
        var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        monthCount = 12 * row;
        totalDeposit = 12.0 * monthlyContribution * row;
        balance = monthlyContribution * (
          (Math.pow(interestFactor, monthCount + 1) - 1) /
          (interestFactor - 1) - 1);
        perviousYearInterest = yearInterest;
        yearInterest = balance - totalDeposit;
        addValueToRow(newRow, "" + row);
        addValueToRow(newRow, formatMoney(monthlyContribution * 12.0));
        addValueToRow(newRow, formatMoney(yearInterest - perviousYearInterest));
        addValueToRow(newRow, formatMoney(totalDeposit));
        addValueToRow(newRow, formatMoney(balance - totalDeposit));
        addValueToRow(newRow, formatMoney(balance));
        table.appendChild(newRow);
      }
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < inputBoxes.length; i += 1) {
      inputBoxes[i].oninput = updateTable;
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", main, false);

})();
```

```css
:root {
  --system-font-stack: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

body {
  font-family: var(--system-font-stack);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

#user-inputs>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

#user-inputs label {
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
}

#user-inputs input {
  width: 15rem;
}

#interest-table,
#interest-table thead,
#interest-table tr {
  width: 100%;
}

#interest-table>thead>tr>td {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#interest-table td {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Compound Interest Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Compound Interest Calculactor</h1>
  <div id="user-inputs">
    <div>
      <label for="monthly-contribution">Monthly Contribution</label>
      <input type="text" id="monthly-contribution" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="annual-interest-rate">Annual Interest Rate (%)</label>
      <input type="text" id="annual-interest-rate" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="year-count">Number of Years</label>
      <input type="text" id="year-count" />
    </div>
    <table id="interest-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Year</td>
          <td>Year Deposit</td>
          <td>Year Interest</td>
          <td>Total Deposit</td>
          <td>Total Interest</td>
          <td>Balance</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="results">
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="_scripts/compound-interest.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

### A few notes:

- The function `clearContents(tag)` can be simplified to `tag.innerHTML = ''`
- You probably shouldn't be naming your function `main`, as it doesn't describe what it does.
- You should use **`const`** and **`let`** when they are more appropriate than `var`.
- In your HTML, all of your `<input>`'s are `type='text'`, at least `#year-count` should be `type='number'`
- In `perviousYearInterest` you spelled "previous" wrong, unless you meant "pervious".
- Try scoping your variables to an object when they have a repeated part of their names.

For example, take this:

```
monthlyContributionInput = ...
numberOfYearsInput = ...
annualInterestRateInput = ...
```

It becomes:

```
inputs = {
  monthlyContribution: ...,
  numberOfYears: ...,
  annualInterestRate: ...
}
```

- Instead of doing `.appendChild` `.createElement` and `.removeChild`, why not just use `.innerHTML`

Here's the function `main` but using `.innerHTML` to render all of the HTML elements at once, in what I would consider a much more readable manner.

```
function main() {
  // turn input boxes into an Array
  const inputBoxes = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("input"));
  const table = document.getElementById("results");

  // store the inputs in an object to group them together
  const inputs = {
    monthlyContribution: document.getElementById("monthly-contribution"),
    numberOfYears: document.getElementById("year-count"),
    annualInterestRate: document.getElementById("annual-interest-rate")
  };

  const updateTable = function(event) {
    const years = Number(numberOfYearsInput.value);

    const monthlyContribution = Number(inputs.monthlyContribution.value);
    const yearlyContribution = monthlyContribution * 12;
    // No need to recalculate yearly contribution every loop

    const annualInterestRate = Number(annualInterestRateInput.value) / 100.0;
    const interestFactor = 1 + annualInterestRate / 12.0;
    let yearInterest = 0;
    let previousYearInterest = 0;

    // no need to clear table since we're replacing all of the `.innerHTML`

    table.innerHTML = [...Array(years)]
      .map(year => {
        ++year;
        const totalDeposit = yearlyContribution * year;
        const balance = monthlyContribution * ((Math.pow(interestFactor, monthCount + 1) - 1) / (interestFactor - 1) - 1);

        previousYearInterest = yearInterest;
        yearInterest = balance - totalDeposit;

        return `
          <tr>
            <td>${year}</td>
            <td>${formatMoney(yearlyContribution)}</td>
            <td>${formatMoney(yearInterest - previousYearInterest)}</td>
            <td>${formatMoney(totalDeposit)}</td>
            <td>${formatMoney(yearInterest)}</td>
            <td>${formatMoney(balance)}</td>
          </tr>
        `;
      }).join('')
  };

  // iterate over input boxes, instead of for loop
  inputBoxes.forEach(input => input.oninput = updateTable)
}
```

This also makes it somewhat easier to move over to a framework that uses JSX if you ever wish to, because this style is very similar to JSX.